# borders around axis labels in R

Tags: r, ggplot2, viewport, axis-labels

I am trying to create box around axis labels. 
I draw a barchart using the following code

```
df <- data.frame(dose=c("D0.5", "D1", "D2"),
                 len=c(4.2, 10, 29.5))

library(ggplot2)
# Basic barplot
p<-ggplot(data=df, aes(x=dose, y=len)) +
  geom_bar(stat="identity")
p
# Horizontal bar plot
p + coord_flip()
```

which gives the following barcharts

https://i.stack.imgur.com/WxNtc.jpg

[image]

I can easily remove the ticks from the x axis. 
what I am trying to do is adding cells around the x axis labels.

https://i.stack.imgur.com/Ltk31.jpg

[image]

Please can you help me with drawing these cells/rectangular boxes around the labels.

also, I can remove the ticks on the y axis, and I am trying to add ticks between y-axis labels such as this pic

https://i.stack.imgur.com/f6Ab0.jpg

[image]

Please can someone suggest how I can achieve this without creating separate viewports.